# Использование DirectX 12 ultimate через c#

Tags: c#, графика, directx

Делаю свой 3д движок пока на OpenGL через OpenTK естественно на c#. Планирую в будущем сменить api на DirectX. Я знаю про SharpDX, но как написано на их сайте с 2019 года он не разрабатывается и не поддерживается, т.е. он умер. Но мне по плану нужен dxr, который присутствует только в ultimate версии DirectX 12. Есть ли какие либо способы использовать DirectX с dxr через c# на данный момент. Или dxr или рейтрейсинг через Vulkan, но на сколько я понимаю Vulkan сложнее и на него у меня не получилось накопать. Так что в итоге, какие способы использования рейтрейсинга есть в c#?

Comment: Самому интероп написать можно. Готовых решений вы вряд-ли найдёте.